# Splice file from an object javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using multiple file upload in a web application using html

`input` `type` `file` and `multiple` attribute.

The files are accessing in javascript using   `$('#id_docfile').get(0).files` I need to delete some files depending on its extension, from that object before performing submit(`$('form_id').submit()`)
I have tried `delete $('#id_docfile').get(0).files.i`.But the object is not filter out unwanted files.How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to splice the unwanted data, you can just filter it. First you need to push the multiple files in an array, then filter the unwanted data by checking the necessary condition into another array.

```
function uploadFile(){
    var files = [];
    var file = document.querySelector('input[id="fileUpload"]').files;
    if (file) {
        $.each(file, function(i,v) {
            // extension extraction process
            var startIndex = (v.name.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? v.name.lastIndexOf('\\') : v.name.lastIndexOf('/'));
            var filename = v.name.substring(startIndex);
            filename = filename.substring(1);
            var extension = filename.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

            if (extension == "jpg") { // check the necessary condition
                files.push(v);
            }
        });
        console.log(files); // 'files' will contain the desired files
    }
}
```